# Ubuntu terminal connecting to localhost:8080 instead of internet.. Help?

Tags: terminal, ubuntu-10.10

I have changed some settings a while ago in my Ubuntu. Now I open up my box and the terminal doesn't connect to internet instead connects to localhost:8080 (I observed this when i was doing apt-get install somepackage). Is there any way I can restore my terminal to use internet instead?

- Lalith

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check the Network Settings and Proxy Settings. Chances are, you have set a system-wide proxy to localhost:8080. You can access `gnome-network-preferences` from the terminal, and uncheck your proxy, and apply system-wide.